# Input text field on Popup window and populate that field value into custom object field

Tags: apex, visualforce, bootstrap

I have a popup window and a text filed on the popup, if i enter some value in that field and click on yes i need to populate the field field into the custom object field which is having same field.

Can any one please help me on that by providing sample code.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please update your question and provide some of your code and show us where you're stuck? Your question is too generic and has potentially multiple solutions

Comment: Do you mind me asking how this popup might be generated?
If by using buttons, then you might use javascript, but if you have anything else in mind .......

Comment: I am able to get popup by clicking on button using bootstrap. After getting the popup there is a field on the popup window , if i enter any value on that field and click on Yes the value must be saved on other custom object field.

Comment: You should update this question here with parts of your code.

Comment: Here membership is the custom object, so i need to populate the popup text field in the membership object field

Comment: Ok. I see. 
Do you mind me asking for your brief description of your environment?
Because for me, I use the standard SF interface directly in the browser.
I go to the Salesforce setup page, go to the object in question, then go to the buttons section.
When adding the button, I then code in the necessary javascript to make the field entry happen.
honestly, i have not used Bootstrap before.
Also, from your code samples above, looks like you are using visualforce page?

Comment: Edit the question - don't post code in the comments - it's impossible to read!